# taking certain lines from log files on linux

Tags: linux

i have log files in the current structure:

```
STDAT #668324
CSPEC
--Visitor--
IP2LOC:N/A
Time:0900
DOW:1
OS:Windows NT 5.1
Browser:Firefox 3.5
IP:128.64.55.129
```

i know linux is probably king of command line tool, so is their a tool such as "getlines" or something so i can extract lines from text file? the only lines i need are "OS" and "Browser", and i want to add them all to 1 single txt file for graphing. what command can i use to take those 2 lines from this txt file? I have thousands of files like this from my website which are created by PHP, but since site is now bigger, I will be using a database, but i do not want these files to go to waste since this information is still useful.

Answer (score 6):

This should just return the OS and Browser lines from the file:

```
egrep '(OS|Browser)' filename
```

If you have lots of log files, you can use an *

```
egrep '(OS|Browser)' /path/to/logs/*
```

You can redirect this output into a new log file

```
egrep '(OS|Browser)' /path/to/logs/* > summary.log
```

If you wanted to strip the `OS:` and `Browser:` from the start of each line, you could use awk

```
egrep '(OS|Browser)' /path/to/logs/* | awk -F: '{print $2}' > summary.log
```

Answer (score 2):

**`theotherreceive`** has very nicely explained the solution.

Just one thing to add,
If you suspect that that **`OS`** or **`Browser`** terms can occur elsewhere in your log file text,

```
egrep '(^OS:|^Browser:)' filename
        -  - -       -   # Note: extra parts for catching your keys better
```

will help you check that.
This is assuming the two terms appear at the start of the line and are followed with **'`:`'** character.
The rest as already described in that answer.

Comment: +1 I hadn't thought of a case where that would occur.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that all your files are under one directory, for example: /var/www/html/logs and it's subdirectory. Let's assume that all log files end with ".log". Let's assume that you want the combined log to /home/username/combinedlog.txt

There is a unix-tool called "find" that searches for files in given directory tree, for example

```
find /var/www/html/logs -name '*.log' -type f -print
```

would print names of all files ending with '.log' from directory /var/www/html/logs and it's subdirectories.

As the previous answers show, you can get just the OS with *"grep OS:|tail -c +4"* and just the Browser with *"grep OS:|tail -c +4"*. The first answer also shows how to make for-loop with results of one command. So the combined answer would be:

```
for i in `find /var/www/html/logs -name '*.log' -type f -print`; do 
  grep "OS:" $i |tail -c +4 >> /home/username/combinedlog.txt; 
  grep "Browser:" $i|tail -c +9 >> /home/username/combinedlog.txt; 
done;
```

And this would go through all files at once. Note that ">>" is append to a file, if you run this again without removing the previous combined log file, you will duplicate the contents!

Edit: or you could use egrep + awk from the previous answer and replace the two greps with one egrep + awk. You could also use "cut" instead of "tail" or "awk".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with theotherreceive's answer.  And, since maybe you're going to get a *lot* of duplicate lines and maybe you just want to count them ...

```
egrep '(OS|Browser)' /path/to/logs/* | sort | uniq -c
```

Piping the output through sort and uniq -c will give you a count of the number of times each browser or OS is in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the magic abilities of `grep` and `tail`!

To return the browser:

```
 cat file.txt | grep Browser: | tail -c +9
```

To return the OS:

```
cat file.txt | grep OS: | tail -c +4
```

If you want to write them to a text file, this should work:

```
 cat file.txt | grep OS: >> results.txt && cat file.txt | grep Browser: >> results.txt
```

<sub>There are probably other solutions out there, but I am not all that nifty at Bash and the sorts like that, so this is the best I came up with.</sub>

Comment: hi, do i need to type both commands for every file? i have a few thousand.